# Highlighting corresponding points in adjacent plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem with highlighting corresponding points on plots in python using matplotlib. I tried to do it by using a function that reads data from plots when I click the point with a mouse(onpick). Then I try to annotate this information in other adjacent plots. I have a problem with using variables from the onpick function in the annotate command. I would like to use the `ind` parameter from the `onpick` function in the `annotate` command, but python doesn't see it. This is the `onpick` function:

```
def onpick(event):
    thisline = event.artist
    xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
    ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
    global ind
    ind = event.ind
    print('x:', xdata[ind],'y:',ydata[ind])
```

I call the function using this command:

```
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
```

Annotating:

```
ax = plt.subplot2grid((lg, 2), (0, 0), colspan=2)
    ax.plot(t, mp, picker=1)
    ax.set_title('map')
    ax.annotate('here',(t[ind],mp[ind]),xytext=(0.8,0.9),
                arrowprops=dict(facecolor='grey',color='grey'))
```

Python command box shows this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kubag\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/kubag/Desktop/pyton/wykres/wykres.py", line 78, in graph
    ax.annotate('here',(t[ind],mp[ind]),xytext=(0.8,0.9),arrowprops=dict(facecolor='grey',color='grey'))
NameError: name 'ind' is not defined
```

Whole code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t=range(10)
mp=range(10)
v=range(10)

def onpick(event):
    thisline = event.artist
    xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
    ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
    global ind
    ind = event.ind
    print('x:',int(xdata[ind]),'y:',int(ydata[ind]))
    global ind2
    ind2=int(ind)
    ax.annotate('miejsce', (t[ind2], mp[ind2]), xytext=(0.8, 0.9), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='grey'))

fig = plt.figure()
global ax
ax = plt.subplot2grid((1, 2), (0, 0))
ax.plot(t, mp, picker=1)

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 2), (0, 1))
ax1.plot(t, v, picker=1)

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
fig.canvas.draw()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you share a full error trace, please?

Comment: i updated the question so you can see the full error now

Comment: Are you sure you have called `onpick(event)` at least once before calling `ax.annotate('here',(t[ind],mp[ind]),xytext=(0.8,0.9),arrowprops=dict(facecolor='grey',color='grey'))`?

Comment: The problem is i don't know how to call it because of the (event) variable that is in the function. I thought that `fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)` calls this function.

Comment: Can you share a little bit more code so I can run, please?

Comment: Can you give me your email? I will send it to you because it's a bit long

Comment: `fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)` doesn't call the function, it connects it to `PickEvent`, the function will be called when a `PickEvent` occurs ([i.e.](https://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.PickEvent) *when the user picks a location on the canvas sufficiently close to an artist*)

Comment: You don't have the share all the code, just a minimal example that can be run. I suspect you just have to move your `ax.annotate` calls into your `onpick` function and then make sure the canvas is updated, but it would be easier with a run-nable sample.

Comment: @KubaGłowacz Don’t post the code in the comments, add it to your question by editing it. Especially with a language where indentation matters so much like Python it is not always possible to follow code posted in comments without indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `ind` outside the function; it is not sufficient to use `global ind` inside unless you can guarantee that `onpick` will be called before `ind` is used.

Consider

```py
def fun():
    global i
    i = 10
print(i)
```

This raises the error

> ```
> NameError: name 'i' is not defined
> ```

at the line `print(i)`

However,

```py
def fun():
    global i
    i = 10
fun()
print(i)
```

Works perfectly fine. So if you can't ensure that the function (`fun`) will be called before the variable (`i`) is used then simply define the variable outside the function:

```py
i = 0
def fun():
    global i
    i = 10
print(i)
```

That way `i` can be used regardless of whether the function has been called.

—-

Edit

The call to

```
fig.canvas.draw()
```

needs to be inside the `onpick` function and **after** the `ax.annotate` instead of after connecting the function with

```
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
```

otherwise the canvas will not be updated after the `PickEvent`. So `onpick` should look like this

```
def onpick(event):
    thisline = event.artist
    xdata = thisline.get_xdata()
    ydata = thisline.get_ydata()
    global ind
    ind = event.ind
    print('x:',int(xdata[ind]),'y:',int(ydata[ind]))
    global ind2
    ind2=int(ind)
    ax.annotate('miejsce', (t[ind2], mp[ind2]), xytext=(0.8, 0.9), 
                arrowprops=dict(facecolor='grey'))
    fig.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't know how to call this function because of the `(event)` argument. I added `ind=0` before the `onpick` function but it still doesn't update the annotation on the plots.

Comment: @KubaGłowacz The function should be called after a [`PickEvent`](https://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.PickEvent) are you triggering a `PickEvent`?

Comment: So how i should call it after the `PickEvent` occurs? By triggering `PickEvent` you mean clicking the artist with a mouse?

Comment: @KubaGłowacz Yes, the function will be called *by* clicking the artist with the mouse. If you want to manually call it for some reason you should be able to create a `PickEvent` instance and then pass it to `onclick`, otherwise just call it by clicking on the artist

Comment: Not yet, i don't really understand what do you mean by creating `PickEvent` instance and passing it to `onclick`.

Comment: @KubaGłowacz I’m sorry, `onclick` was a typo - I meant `onpick`, I will add an example of how to call `onpick` manually to my answer. Is `onpick` is being called when you click on an artist in the plot?

Comment: Thank you! I also had to make the fig variable global and it works :)

Comment: @KubaGłowacz I’m glad to hear that, be sure to hit [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so that the question is marked as such for future users